# How to change global variable value fully during run time - javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to change global variable value (fully) during run time in "for function" in java script ..

my code:

```
for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
var test;

test = i;

if (test == 5)
{
test = "the end";
}

if (test == "the end")
{
alert("the end");
}
}
```

i want to change test variable value to "the end" string or what i want and make it static ..

how can i make `test` variable always = "the end" in for function ?!

how can i do it ?

thanks.

Comment: i tried to put variable outside "for function" and then change the value directly to be static in the program , but it's not declared in the "for function" ..

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal it's not declared in the "for function" ...

Comment: Uh, yes it is declared in the for loop.

Comment: That's not correct JavaScript has functional scope so the var keyword is global regardless of where you put it. Unless you put it in a function that is. If you want to make test  equal to 6 then change your for loop condition to I<7. At this point test = 6. Again JavaScript has functional scope and block level scope was only recently added with ES6 let keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to persist `"the end"` as the value of `test` you have a few options.

1. Do you want the `for` loop to execute fully (in this case from 0 to 100)?

   If so, then you should *only set the value of `test` when your conditions are met*. Right now you are setting the value to `i` on every iteration. When `i === 5` you are setting `test = "the end"` but on the very next iteration it will get overwritten with `test = i`. To fix this:

   ```
   var test;

   for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     if (i === 5) {
       test = "the end";
     }

     if (test === "the end") {
       alert(test);
     }
   }
   ```
2. If you want iteration *to stop when the value gets to `5`*... then you'll want to [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) out of the loop:

   ```
   var test;

   for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     if (i === 5) {
       test = "the end";
       break;
     }
   }

   alert(test);
   ```